# Extjs 3.4 problems rendering buttons in toolbar

Tags: javascript, extjs

Using Extjs 3.4. I am creating a top Toolbar above a grid.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var colModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
        columns: [{
            header: "Sottogruppo",dataIndex: 'some'
        }],
        defaults: {
            width: 50,
            sortable: false
        }
    });

    var saveButton = new Ext.Button({text: "Salva",id: 'save'});    

    var tbar = new Ext.Toolbar({items: [saveButton]});

    var grid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
        colModel: colModel,
        tbar: tbar
    });
    grid.render("grid");
});
```

The chrome console show this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSortState' of undefined ../JS/ext-3.3.1/ext-all-debug.js
```

Ideas?

***SOLUTION***
add a store in the grid config:

```
store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a required configuration option `store`. The error is related, the grid code tries to find out sort state of the store but it is not defined.

Comment: I have added a store, now it works. store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore()